# How to implement Depth Page Transformer like animation in react native using react native pager view

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-animated, react-native-pager-view

I want to implement Depth page transformer([example](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/screen-slide-2#depth-page)) like animation in react native using package [`react-native-pager-view`](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view). Is it possible to do it, can anybody guide me in the right direction?